# How to edit automatically generated model in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

```
protected function beforeSave()
{
  if(parent::beforeSave())
  {
     if($this->isNewRecord)
     {
        $this->create_time = $this->update_time=time();
        $this->author_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
     }
     else
        $this->update_time = time();
     return true;
 }
 else
    return false;
```

}

Above is a sample code of model.
Can anybody tell me how to edit such automatic generated code in Yii?

Comment: You would first have to explain why the obvious if cheeky answer "using your preferred code editor" is not good enough.

Comment: I want to edit this model using Gii tool but hows?

Answer (score 0):

```
       $this->author_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
```

It's bad practice. Because you model depend from your environment.  in consequence of dependecy you cant use Unit-test and console command for creating models.